# css give 2 class the same color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for my homepage. In there I have different Panels with bootstrap-colors such like

`<div class="panel panel-info">`

now I want to add explanations what the different colors mean.  so I made some labels

`<h5><span class="label label-info">new panel</span></h5>`.

But, they have different colors in Bootstrap. My way to solve this, I found the color-description in `bootstrap.min.css` for `panel-info` and c&p this to my own css:

```
.label-info{
 color:#31708f;
 background-color:#d9edf7;
 border-color:#bce8f1;
 }
```

It works, but my question is, is there a more simple way to do this? to give 2 classes the same color/attribute? like `.label-info = .panel-info>.panel-heading` or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify same attributes to different `selectors` by separating them with a `,`:

```
.label-info,
.panel-info>.panel-heading {
    ....
}
```

Comment: yeah, I know that, but what if, in my case `.panel-info>.panel-heading`,  is pre-defined?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Bootstrap styles can be overridden. You just need to create the above styles in a separate stylesheet which you must append to page after the bootstrap css files.

Comment: yeah, thats why I put my own `.label-info` in my html file so it can overwrite the one from bootstrap.min.css. And with your solution, I still have to write the color/background-color/border-color lines "manually" in the  {}? so your solution is actually longer than mine? :-)  I was looking for a way that a new class can simply inherit(or clone) the attribute from an exsting one(which I shouldn't change)

Comment: You only need to specify the attributes that you wish the `override` or `add`. I don't see you having a solution because  `selector1 = selector2` is not a valid CSS rule.

Comment: Another option would be to create a new custom class, for example `.custom-theme-panel` which has the new attributes and which you will add to the elements that you wish to change.